# How to lazyload a controller in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oclazyload

In my angularjs app I am trying to lazyload a controller like this:

```
$scope.loadView4Ctrl = function () {
    console.log('loadview4ctrl');

    $ocLazyLoad.load({
        name: "View4",
        files: [
            'view4/view4.js'
        ]
    });
};
```

When I run this my view4Ctrl does not get loaded? How can I run this controller through ocLazyLoad?

This is the controller I am trying to load:

```
'use strict';

console.log('loading file containing view4Ctrl');
app
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view4', {
            templateUrl: 'view4/view4.html',
            controller: 'view4Ctrl'
        });
    }])
    .controller('view4Ctrl', function () {
        console.log('This is lazy loaded!!!');

        $scope.hello='Good day , I am loaded now.';

    });
```

Here is the [code](https://github.com/dimitri-a/angular-seed/tree/stack)

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution**

> In your `view4/view4.js`, change `app.config` to `angular.module('myApp').config`

**RCA**

> When `view4.js` gets lazy-loaded by `$ocLazyLoad`, the context to `app` variable has changed.

I did clone your code from GitHub to test the above resolution, and it works :)

Hope it helps!